# How can I detect unknown face on face recognition Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-recognition

I am trying to test face recognition program using EmguCV. I have my source code form this 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real-ti
I try to capture myself and it can recognize me. But when someone whose face isn't trained yet, it recognize as me.

can't anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some inaccuracy using OpenCV.
I'd like to give you two suggestions: 1.Train as many persons as you can. The lager database is, the more accuracy it will be. 2.Try another library. Some more professional facial recognition libraries.

Recently I have found a facial technology [Face++](http://www.faceplusplus.com/). I'm developing an Android APP using their API. It's amazing, easier to use than OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code to implement face recognition and I faced the same issue.

Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457827/how-to-get-confidence-value-in-face-recognition-using-emgu-cv/9466619#9466619) that can help you solve your issue. It explains how to modify your EigenRecognizer.cs code

Comment: This should be a comment, or expand a little bit on what the link contains and why it helps the OP.